# Updating the android gradle 3.0 to 5.1 getting error on runtime

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade the gradle and libraries for my application getting runtime error as below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':UIModule:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Gradle:-

```
buildscript {
repositories {`enter code here`
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

   }
 }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {

mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
jcenter()
}


 android {
flavorDimensions "default"
signingConfigs {
    config {
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kisan.samvaad"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 128
    versionName "1.32.20190424.00"
    multiDexEnabled true

    //giving support for ndk
    ndk {
        moduleName "webp"
    }
    //getting error some file crunching fail
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), 
  "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

defaultConfig{
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

ext {
    enableCrashlytics = true
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://leocad.io/mvn' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

productFlavors {
    Dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }

    Staging {
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
    }
    Prod {

    }
}
sourceSets { Prod { java.srcDirs = ['src/Prod/java', 'src/Prod/java/'] 
} }

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDir s = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
  }

 ext {
smackVersion = '4.2.3'
}
configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-
 annotations'
})
implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
implementation files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.+'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-
 loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-
 layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.27.0'
implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-
 extensions:4.1.7') {
    exclude module: 'smack-omemo'
    exclude module: 'smack-omemo-signal'
  }

implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:$smackVersion"
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-
experimental:$smackVersion"
implementation("org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:$smackVersion") 
{
    exclude module: 'smack-omemo'
    exclude module: 'smack-omemo-signal'
}
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:$smackVersion"
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-legacy:$smackVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation project(':BusinessLogicModule')
implementation project(':sdkui')
ext.enableCrashlytics = true
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}


 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just delete `.iml` from project folder and try to rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

Given the compilation error, you are most likely hitting the change that Gradle 5.x will no longer place dependencies declared in Maven metadata as `<scope>runtime</scope>` on the *compile* classpath. Have a look at the [migration notes](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel5.0:pom_compile_runtime_separation) for this.

The easiest way to debug this is to run: `./gradlew :UIModule:dependencies --configuration <configurationName>` where `<configurationName>` is replaced with the right name, which I do not know. If you do not have that information available, simply run the task without the `--configuration` parameter.
Running this with the old and new Gradle versions will allow to figure out the difference and resolve it by adding the missing dependencies where it makes sense.

Note that jumping from 3.x to 5.x may also force you to perform further updates.